# Database consistency for a distributed system

Tags: database, database-design, distributed-computing, distributed-system, server-side

I'm working on a phone call monitoring project. The aim is to have one row in the `calls` table for each ongoing call. Each call instance may be updated by many different servers/threads as more information is gathered about the call. Each call instance (a row) is mapped to a Java object. When a server/thread needs to update a call, it will read the call, apply the update, and then write the call back to the database.

This obviously introduces consistency problems, if a separate update `U2` writes in between the read and write of another update `U1`, then when `U1` is written, it writes stale data.

My current idea to fix this is to capture the changes for an update. When an update happens, it will read a "last updated" time. Then, the changes are applied and written back to the database conditionally (only written if last updated is equivalent to what was read). If the "last updated" time has changed, then a retry is executed, re-reading the data, applying changes, and attempting another write. This will retry the write 3-5 times before giving up.

This has some drawbacks in regards to performance, but is the best I was able to come up with. There is also the rare yet possible problem of retries executing out of order (across different updates). I'm hoping to make all changes independent of the order they are executed in, and I know that order shouldn't be relied on. A good example of this is call status. Say update `U1` sets a call status to `ongoing` and `U2` sets it to `finished`. If `U1` fails, `U2` completes successfully, and then `U1` completes on a retry, the status will be incorrectly set to `ongoing`. One option is only allow `ongoing` to be set when the call status isn't `finished`, but this isn't always clear of all fields and feels a bit messy. There are always options to try to update columns individually, come up with some sort of merging policy, or something else.

My primary goals are consistency and performance. While these criteria are somewhat contradictory, NoSQL seems like a decent tradeoff for my goal (my decision is described more below).

My questions:

- Is there a better way to achieve this goal? It feels sloppy to have every change get recorded as deltas and executed in a retry loop, but I'm not sure if there's a better way to do it.
- I'm currently using NoSQL. Data loss is tolerable, so replication is disabled. I am using conditional transactions to implement updates. Is this the right technology for the job? With replication disabled, I expect that to help considerably in addressing the performance hits introduced by transactions. Scylla/Cassandra's ring hashing seems to be an efficient way to distribute the data, especially with the added benefit of handling call data close to its geographic location. I've also considered Redis, but decided against it as the added database i/o isn't significant, as well as Redis's (somewhat?) poor distributed performance.

It seems like locks would work well in this scenario, but I'm not sure if NoSQL/Scylla supports locks. Should I switch to something that does?

Appreciate the help, will edit with any information if needed. Thanks!

Edit:
Kafka seems like a compelling choice. There are a few queries I'm not sure how I'd make work with Kafka though.

Here are the particular queries I'd like to make efficient:

- Update an existing (ongoing) call by the from number, to number, and status, creating the call if it doesn't exist.
- Update an existing call by id. (Each call is assigned a unique UUID.)
- Query the `N` most recent calls from a particular number
- Query a call by its from number, to number, and status.

I was thinking to make a new topic for each new instance of a call. Another potential route would be to have one topic for every phone number, and call events are written to this topic for all calls originating from that number.

Comment: Is it an option to store the changes themselves in an append-only manner and only reconstruct the full state of a call when needed?

Comment: Is noSql a hard requirement, or have you concidered using a database with support for transactions (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html)? Also, retry loops are indeed sloppy, look for an event queue pattern

Comment: +1 for Bart's suggestion. You can partition the changes by phone number for example. You can also have an hourly/daily process that processes all "closed" calls to reduce the amount of data stored.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I am trying to model most requests that way as much as possible, but there will be an occasional update that overwrites a value.

Comment: @s.lg It's not a hard requirement, just chosen for its horizontal scalability. Horizontal scalability is important in this application.

Comment: @user253751 This is what I'm currently doing, phone numbers are partitioned. Secondly, one of the reasons I chose a database over a cache is because I do want the data to be logged for improving the system and understanding its performance (a little data lost doesn't matter much though). Great idea though, will be using some sort of a cleaning process or TTL.

Comment: You could also consider routing the events about a call to the same thread on the server in the first place, *if your architecture allows it*, so no locking is needed in the database. As I understand it, each call only has a moderate rate of events which is low enough for one thread to process many calls? But I don't see an obvious way to do the routing for this idea. (Edit: Kafka may be able to do it?)

Comment: @user253751 This would be possible, but wouldn't that mean I need a thread for every call? Would that be performant? Yes, each call itself has very few events to process. Kafka seems interesting. I'm not sure how an event consumer would look though. A challenge is that some requests need to pull a call and inspect some data of it. I'm not sure how this would work in an event driven system aside from pre-emptively sending the call, but its hard to know which server will handle the request (my frontend servers are distributed as well).

Comment: @wdavies973 Each thread would process a partition of the calls, not just one call. All the synchronization would happen in your code, not in the database. As I said I'm not sure about the routing.

Comment: @user253751 I added some more details on how I'm thinking of using Kafka, any thoughts on this?

Answer (score -1):

Why are you looking at NoSQL? More traditional databases that guarantee [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) will make your life easier. Transactions that fail don't leave data, they can be logged and only the failures you care about can be retried instead of everything. Locking is complicated to implement on you own, and all relational databases come with advanced locking patterns. NoSQL isn't really guaranteed to be better performance compared to a SQL database that is well designed. Especially if some data loss is acceptable you can tweak values in relational databases so the overhead of transactions won't bottleneck you, so you get 99% of their benefit without the drawback.

Another option that probably better matches your requirements is an event focused system. Something like Kafka. With this approach you can send all updates through topics and then decide as you consume them if the update is properly in order or should be discarded. This can all happen in a very quick time frame and in the case of Kafka is also distributed. the event streaming approach seems to closely match your use case. you could probably even reduce the need to do a read before a write and simply send what should get updated to Kafka, then decide if that update should be applied to the "current state" on a per field or as a whole basis. Because all your activity is stored as a log you could even have a mostly right version of data with up to the ms updates and a totally right up to the second updates of your data if that becomes desirable.

Comment: Given that the OP's read-modify-conditional-write cycles are having to be retried up to 5 times, it seems there's a large volume of data, possibly too much for a traditional database.

Comment: @user253751 is correct, there will be a large amount of data. NoSQL itself isn't that important, it's NoSQL's horizontal scalability that is important. A more traditional solution that is highly scalable would be fine as well. Kafka seems interesting, I'll take a look. Thanks!

Comment: @wdavies973 NoSQL has horizontal scalability with ease because it's performance sucks without it. there are very few dataflows that NoSQL actually does better at than a traditional relational database especially when it comes to ACID or transactions.

Comment: I added some more details on how I'm thinking of using Kafka, any thoughts on this?